# Nivo Slider custom height/width problems

Tags: html, css, wordpress, nivo-slider

I have searched for a resolution to my problem, but have not yet been successful.

I have images of different sizes in `Nivo Slider`, but I need to create a `viewport` that displays the image centered in a `div`. It's hard to explain, but I have included a diagram below.

The image must be centered in a `div`, while the `div` must also be responsive. I don't want the `div` to change its size and would like the image to create an `overflow` that is hidden on the `div`.

[image: Nivo slider test image]

I have tried different methods of `CSS` and `HTML`, but neither are my greatest strengths.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML and CSS you are currently using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want to achieve is something like this (uncommenting `/*overflow: hidden;*/`): [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/t5dq8sgm/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg"/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div{
    position: relative;
    margin: 100px auto;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 3px solid red;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Note: I comment `overflow: hidden;` so you can see how the image is positioned.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply, that's exactly what i am looking for, Thanks. I'll test that now and come back to you.