# Align image center and retain aspect ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of images that i want to create a set of buttons with titles from. My attempt so far is below....

Issue: the images seem to be skewed to reduce their width but not their height or indeed not stretch to their max size possible.

How can i keep the aspect ratio and center the image for 3 images each in their own column and of different sizes.

```
   <div class="row row-bottomspace">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">     
        <!--carouselstart-->
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <img src="img/home/contactus.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3 class="sitetext">Contact us</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/home/gallery.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3 class="sitetext">Our Gallery</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div>
                        <img src="img/home/facebook.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">  
                        <h3 class="sitetext">Visit our Facebook page</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.row-topspace {
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.row-bottomspace {
    padding-bottom: 2%;

.sitetext {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Cooper Black';
    font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: Try adding height:auto; to .img-responsive. This is assuming you don't need the image to align vertically in it's parent.

Comment: thx, to where should i add this?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30945782/4908989) is what you are looking for :) [See this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/t5dq8sgm/4/) please.

Comment: No, this does nothing and does not solve the centering of image issue

Comment: can you include your css or are you just using the bootstrap css?

Comment: Sure let me include any css referred to outside of bootstrap. done

Comment: @Imgonzalves - thx but this is way too specific for what i want (overflows etc) i just want to cetner my pic and keep its aspect correct with its height the height of its parent

Comment: @Fearghal So you'd like the height to always match it's parent but the width to overflow?

Comment: tbh - lets just center the image, how can i do this?

Comment: Vertically and horizontally? Some of the answer linked to by @lmgonzalves will help you there.

Comment: Ok How can i do it horizontally?

Comment: I cant get it to work, theimage always seems stuck to the left its parent div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hpffr00s/

Answer (score 0):

got a adequate solution, not perfect but simple. I set the parent div of the image to class="thumbnail" which by result centers the image" without distorting it. If anybody has a css only method then il set their answer to correct....

```
   <div class="row row-bottomspace">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">     
        <!--carouselstart-->
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center sitetext">
                    <div class="thumbnail siteImageButton">
                        <img src="img/home/contactus.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Contact us</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail siteImageButton">
                        <img src="img/home/gallery.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">
                        <h3>Our Gallery</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail siteImageButton">
                        <img src="img/home/facebook.png" alt="residential image not available" class="img-responsive">  
                        <h3>Visit our Facebook page</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```